# Find the residue of the function $f(z) = e^{(z^2)/(z^n)}$ at all its poles.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis

I'm currently working on this problem, and I think there is a trick to it because of the $z^2$ in the exponent of e. I fail to see it though.

Find the residue of the function $f(z) = e^{(z^2)/(z^n)}$ at all its poles.

Comment: What do we know about $n$?  Is $n$ an integer?

Comment: What poles?  This has no poles. $0$ is an essential singularity (if $n$ is an integer $>2$), or a branch point if $n$ is not an integer.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that $n$ is supposed to be an integer.

**Hint:** $f$ only fails to be complex-differentiable at $z = 0$ (which is a singularity, but not a pole).  Using the series $e^x = \sum_k \frac 1{k!}x^k$, we can express $f(z)$ as a Laurent series centered at $z = 0$.  Using the Laurent series, we can find the desired residue.